# Give Databricks Unity Catalog enabled cluster user root privileges

Tags: apache-spark, odbc, databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I'm migrating the current hive metastore tables in my Azure Databricks workspace to Unity Catalog (UC), and I encountered and issue related to privileges with the new user.

So my cluster setting will be something like:

- DBR 13.3 LTS
- Mode: Shared (UC enabled)
- Cluster config has an init_script which runs `apt-get` and other commands in order to install the ODBC driver

So noticed that if I run: `%sh whoami` in the non-UC cluster I would get `root` as a response, which was great because the init_script would run the apt-get and commands to install the ODBC driver, but now I run the same `%sh whoami` in the UC enabled cluster I will get something like spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af.

Then I run `%sh id spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af` and I get something like:

`uid=1119(spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af) gid=1119(spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af) groups=1119(spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af)`

With the non-UC enabled cluster I would get something like:

`uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)`

I tried running commands like:

`%sh usermod -u 0 spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af`

or

`%sh visudo spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`

To see if I can grant the user `spark-XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-af` same privileges as `root` before in the non-UC cluster, but I was unsuccessful.

Does anyone has faced this issue, and got a solution to this? Either by granting root privileges to the UC-enabled user or any way of installing ODBC in a UC-enabled cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `%sh whoami` command on the Shared UC cluster, it's executed in the isolated environment that is necessary to protect users from each other, so no commands like `visudo`, etc. won't help.

But the init script is still executed as `root` - you can check this by creating a simple init script with content like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

whoami
```

and if you enable cluster logs, then you should see in the file for the standard output that it has the `root` there.

Comment: So tried creating a simple init script looking like: `#!/bin/bash whoami`

Inside a Volume called `test_init_scripts` which is inside a schema from a UC catalog, and assigned to the cluster advanced option> init scripts: `/Volumes/catalogname/schemaname/test_init_scripts/whoami-test.sh`

But the cluster still gets an error trying to execute it:
`Init script failure:
Cluster scoped init script /Volumes/catalogname/schemaname/test_init_scripts/whoami-test.sh failed: Script exit status is non-zero`

Comment: enable cluster logs, and check init scripts

Comment: So the stdout log doesn't show anything (assuming the script never manages to run, so no output to show), but the stderr log shows a message like: `'bash: /Volumes/catalogname/schemaname/test_init_scripts/whoami-test.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory\n'`

Comment: you have DOS-style line endings (`\r\n`) - you need to use dos2unix (or similar tool) to convert into Unix-style line ending (`\n`)

Comment: Thanks, so yes that was the problem. For now I have created the init script within a notebook cell like the following `init_script = '#!/bin/bash\nwhoami'` and `with open("/Volumes/catalogname/schemaname/test_init_scripts/whoami-test.sh", "w") as file:
    file.write(init_script)` and now cluster works. Probably will automate this better in the future, but definitely will keep in touch for other UC related migration questions ;)